# How to hide softkeyboard when user tap outside the dialog

Tags: android, dialog, keyboard

If the user taps a space not on the soft keyboard or on the edittext, the dialog will dismiss, how can I dismiss keyboard in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this method to hide keyboard:

```
 public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (inputManager!=null) {
                if (activity.getCurrentFocus() == null)
                    return;
                if (activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() == null)
                    return;
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        } catch (Exception hideKeyboardException) {
            // handle exception here
        }
    }
```

If you don't have any activity then remove activity object form this method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, may be it help

```
    public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```